# Install TensorFlow addons

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a venv with the following details:

- **python 3.6**
- **TensorFlow 2.0.0**

I tried to install **tensorflow-addons** using the following:

`pip install -q --no-deps tensorflow-addons~=0.6`

But then I keep receiving the following **error**:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons~=0.6 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons~=0.6
>
> You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.3.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I also tried other versions of tensorflow-addons, e. g., `0.4.0, 0.5.0, ...`, but it did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been related to installing on Windows platforms in the earlier versions of tensorflow-addons. As of time of *updating* this comment this issue should disappear completely.

In fact the developers state it has been solved, as it is shown here:

> FYI stable release for windows is out. pip install tensorflow-addons

https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/173#issuecomment-573106184

Comment: I think others have run into this issue, have a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/222

Comment: Thanks. As explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/173), it is blocked. 

Do you know any work around? How one can do image transformation that are TensorFlow compatible (e.g., one can use tf.graidents on top of them to optimize that)?

Comment: Please don't just paste the link of the answer here. You have to at least partially quote some content from the link. If you can not do that, add the link as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 12):

I came across this problem two times and each time I had to solve the problem with a different solution.

**1. Solution:**

- Upgrade pip/pip3 by using the following command.
  python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
- Select appropriate version of the tensorflow-addons using the
  following link
  https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix
- Install using the following command

  ```
     pip install tensorflow-addons==version
  ```

**2. Solution:**

- go to https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-addons/#history
- click on appropriate version
- click on "Download files" on menu to the left
- click on a .whl file that matches your system
  requirements/specifications
- go to the directory where you download the .whl file and run the
  following

  pip install tensorflow_addons-name.whl

Answer (score 0):

At your command prompt, simply specify the version you want to install.

For me, my python version is 3.7.4 and Tensorflow version is 2.2.0
Therefore, the tensorflow-addons version that matches my python and tensorflow version is 0.10.0

```
   pip install tensorflow-addons==0.10.0
```