# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons<0.8.0,>=0.7.1 (from rasa) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to install Rasa, with the command: `pip3 install rasa`.
However, I came up against an error about tensorflow, which is not automatically installed.
Then I used command: `pip3 install tensorflow`, unfortunately, an error appeared:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons<0.8.0,>=0.7.1 (from rasa) (from versions: none).
So how could I install Rasa, and Tensorflow as well?
P/s: Python --version: 3.8.3;
pip --version: 20.1.1

Answer (score 4):

There is a [version compatibility section](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatility) on TensorFlow Addons which states what combinations of [Python version | Tensorflow Version | Tensorflow Addons Version] is possible.

In your case, TensorFlow addons 0.7.1 is available only for Python versions <= 3.7. The first version available for 3.8 is 0.10.0 which is incompatible with the Rasa requirement.
Maybe, you want to downgrade your python version and use a 3.7 one.

Comment: The error mentioned in the question was generated by tensorflow-addons and by following Complete solution can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102460/install-tensorflow-addons/60724821#60724821 I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've made the same mistake of installing the python version 3.8 when it says on the RASA installation notes that you've got to go for version 3.6 3.7 for now.

After having the right version of Python in my venv (macOS zsh) the installation worked fine. From the python site you can find the right version to prepare for your environment. Also it was advised that you prepare the python version for the venv and not your entire system (which I think is at python 2.x)

Making sure that you have all the components you need and the right version was key for RASA to not have issues during the install.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problems and executed following commands:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`
- `pip3 install rasa`

Now My System is:

1. `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`
2. `Python 3.6.9`
3. `pip 20.3.3`
4. `tensorflow 2.3.1`
5. `tensorflow_addons 0.12.0`

and rasa on my system is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall python 3.7 on my part because after verification it was missing from /usr/bin/ for some reason.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

The following combination of versions worked for me and I was able to train the initial model

```
Python 3.7.7
tensorflow-addon 0.8.3
TensorFlow version 2.1.1
```

You can check tensorflow version by using the following command

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```